# Extracting and filtering columns of data using R by loop

Tags: r, loops, dataframe, filter

I am newbie in R and would appreciate your help. I have a dataframe with 5 columns (fasta files and four strains) of data and 10 rows.

```
     genome <- data.frame(fasta = rnorm(10), strain1 = rnorm(10), strain2 = rnorm(10), strain3 = rnorm(10), strain4 = rnorm(10))
```

I want to split the dataframe into two columns (fasta, and strainn) using a loop so that the end of it all I will have 4 separate csv files with 2 columns of data. In each of the files I want to filter the strain's column that only rows with a given maximum value e.g. 0.5 are in the new dataframes. So far, I can create the dataframes with "function (x) NULL" but I am unable to filter or export the dataframes once I add a filter function. How do I filter and export the files? My codes thus far are.

```
nstrain <- ncol(genome)-1

dataframes <- lapply(1:nstrain, function(x) NULL)

  for (i in 1:nstrain) {
  dataframes[[i]] <- data.frame(genome$fasta, genome[i+1])
  }

dataframes
```

I want to end up with dataframes such as these

```
> dataframes
[[1]]
   genome.fasta    strain1
1    1.04954754 0.2358870
2    0.20305724 0.4763678
3    1.04875114  0.3216317
4    0.05839317 0.2899819
5    0.54135630 0.0100254

[[2]]
   genome.fasta    strain2
1    0.20305724  0.3915370
2    1.04875114 0.3294302
3   -0.03065096 0.4339920
4    0.70639127 0.3092204
5    0.54135630  0.2708824
6   0.65988727 0.4862548

[[3]]
   genome.fasta    strain3
1    0.44547248  0.3196918
2    1.04954754  0.3320331
3    0.54135630  0.3039161

[[4]]
   genome.fasta     strain4
1    0.44547248  0.21858664
2   -0.03065096 0.23830566
```

Your assistance would be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to write separate csv's for each strain, you can use `lapply` :

```
lapply(seq_along(genome[-1]), function(x) {
    write.csv(subset(cbind(genome[1], genome[x+1]), genome[[x + 1]] < 0.6), 
       paste0('strain', x, '.csv'), row.names = FALSE)
})
```

This will give you files `'strain1.csv'`, `'strain2.csv'` etc in your working directory.

---

If you want list of dataframes back, you can remove the `write.csv` part and use

```
data <- lapply(seq_along(genome[-1]),function(x) 
            subset(cbind(genome[1], genome[x+1]), genome[[x + 1]] < 0.6))
```

Comment: Thank you very much. This works, but which code can I add to filter the columns e.g. only rows with maximum value 0.6? Please see my edited question.

Comment: @Joey254 So you want to keep only those rows which are less than 0.6? Check my updated answer.

Comment: It works like a charm. I highly appreciate the guidance.

Comment: One last question. The dataframe code works very fine, but the one for writing the csv files still exports all rows. Could you kindly add the code to select for only <0.6? Thanks

Comment: Okay. Updated the first part of the answer to write only those rows that are <0.6.

Answer (score 0):

```
genome <- data.frame(fasta = rnorm(10), strain1 = rnorm(10), strain2 = rnorm(10), strain3 = rnorm(10), strain4 = rnorm(10))
genome

nstrain = 4
dfs =  vector(mode = "list", length = nstrain)

for(i in 1:nstrain){
  dfs[[i]] = genome[,c(1,i+1)]
  write.csv(dfs[[i]], file = paste0(i,".csv:))

}
```